# useEffect triggers when I change a state value changes to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This thing is driving me crazy I hope someone can light me up!

I have this reducer:

```
    deleteNoteById: (state, action) => {
    //...
    state.active = false;
    //...
    }
```

That reducer changes the state.active to false and should activate this useEffect code that I call from a component:

```
    const { active } = useSelector( state => state.journal );

    useEffect(() => {
    // Code...
    }, [active]);
```

But it doesn't. It only executes the code inside useEffect when the action is different to false.
For example, if the action is something like:

```
    {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        date: new Date().getTime(),
        imagesUrls:[]
    }
```

It will execute the useEffect code but if the action is **false** it won't.

I checked my state with Redux Devtools and the state.active changes to false but the useEffect code won't be executed.

[image: devtools proof]

Diff tab:

[image]

I thought that any change (even set the variable to false) in the useEffect dependencies should triggers it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Redux Toolkit?

Comment: Yep, I'm using it and I can see there that the state changes correctly but useEffect is not executed.

Comment: @AngelQuesada, can you show the diff tab?

Comment: Perhaps you can share the full Store setup? I'm suspecting something wrong is going on with the slices and/or action creators, etc.

Comment: You’re right that the effect executes whenever dependencies change. Add 2 console’s -one inside the function body and one inside the effect. Somethings not adding up here.

Answer (score 0):

in reducer you change **state.active**

but in useSelector you get **state.journal**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
That's working correctly, I get the activate state from the state, the error must be somewhere else.